# git push is very slow for a branch

Tags: git

We have a git repo that is quite large (ios app resources). I appreciate that git is going to be slow when working with it, but if I create a new branch and edit a couple of files (not binary ones) and push, it takes forever.

It feels like the entire repo is being pushed. I was under the impression that git would only send the diff, is that wrong? (I know git stores compressed versions of the whole file, I mean the diff between my branch and where I branched from).

If I run `git diff --stat --cached origin/foo` then I see a short list of files that looks like what I would expect, e.g. `34 files changed, 1117 insertions(+), 72 deletions(-)`. But when I push it gets to `Writing objects:  21% (2317/10804)` and grinds to a halt, as if it's pushing all 2.4GB of binary data.

Am I missing something (I've googled it pretty hard)? Is this the expected behaviour? I'm using git 2.2.2 on OS X (Mavericks), and ssh (git@github.com).

I found a similar question here: [Git - pushing a remote branch for a large project is really slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562594/git-pushing-a-remote-branch-for-a-large-project-is-really-slow) but no real answers.

Comment: see discussion on git mailing list - http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/265716

Comment: Alive link to the thread mentioned by @grahamrhay : https://public-inbox.org/git/CAABECY1_L34sq0VPmD9UwRcwb3Fuh95OFcF26LM2eX1z-+8vkQ@mail.gmail.com/

Comment: For large repos only, you now now (Q1 2019) have, with Git For Windows 2.21, the config `pack.sparse` which can help the performance of the push. That will be generalized for all platform. See "[git push is very slow for a huge repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56172942/6309)"

Comment: See also with Git 2.38 (Q3 2022) the new setting [`git -c push.useBitmaps=false push`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73012939/6309)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You're using a "smart" transport (this is a good thing), so you do get deltas, or more specifically, "delta compression".  But that's not to say that git pushes diffs.

Both push and fetch work the same way here: on a smart transport, your git calls up the remote and both ends have a mini conversation to figure out who has which repository objects, identified by SHA-1 and attached to specific labels (typically branch and tag names although other labels are allowed as well).

For instance, in this case, your git calls up theirs and says: "I propose to have you set your branch `master` to SHA-1 `1234567...`.  I see that your `master` is currently `333333...`, here's what I think you need to get from there to `7777777...`."  Theirs should reply with "ok,  I need some of those but I already have ...".  Once your git has figured out what needs to be sent, and what is already present, your git builds a "thin pack"<sup>1</sup> containing all the to-be-sent objects.  (This is the "delta compressing using up to %d threads" phase.)

The resulting thin pack is then sent over the smart transport; this is where you see the "writing objects" messages.  (The entire thin pack must be sent successfully, after which the receiver "fattens it up" again using `git index-pack --fix-thin` and drops it into the repository.)

Exactly what data is sent, depends on the objects in the thin pack.  That *should* be just the set of commits between "what they have" and "what you're sending", plus any objects (trees and blobs) needed for those commits, plus any annotated tags you're sending and any objects needed for those, that they don't already have.

You can find the commits in question by using `git fetch` to pick up their latest information, then using `git rev-list` to see what commits you'd send them.  For instance, if you're just going to push things on `master`:

```
$ git fetch origin   # assuming the remote name is origin
[wait for it to finish]
$ git rev-list origin/master..master
```

Examining these commits may show a very large binary file that is contained in one of the middle ones, then removed again in a later commit:

```
$ git log --name-status origin/master..master
```

If one commit has `A giantfile.bin` and then a subsequent (probably listed first in `git log` output) commit has `D giantfile.bin`, you're probably getting hung up sending the blob for `giantfile.bin`.

If that's the case, you can use `git rebase -i` to eliminate the commit that adds the giant binary file, so that `git push` won't have to send that commit.

(If your history is linear—has no merges to push—then you can also, or instead, use `git format-patch` to create a series of email messages that contain patches.  These are suitable for emailing to someone at the other site—not that there's someone at github waiting to receive them, but you can easily examine the patch files to see if any of them are enormous.)

---

<sup>1</sup>The pack is "thin" in that it violates a normal pack-file rule that requires any delta-compression "downstream" object to be in the pack itself.  Instead, the "downstream" objects can (in fact, must) be in the repository receiving the thin pack.

Comment: unfortunately, the format-patch totals 1.7MB, which doesn't explain the slow push

Comment: At this point the thing to investigate is what's in the thin-pack, and whether your ssh transport is simply getting stuck (due to some probably-not-git-related network issue).  A network tracer like tcpdump may be helpful for the latter.

Comment: is the thin-pack === git format-patch origin/foo..foo ?

Comment: No: the key difference is that a thin pack contains actual git objects, while `format-patch` makes diffs suitable for emailing.  The diffs provide enough information to reconstruct *files*, but not a complete commit graph, nor tags.  Or, in other words, `format-patch` gets you most but not all information, in a different format.  There's no direct way to compare sizes, although one might reasonably expect a strong positive correlation.

Comment: On the way Git is building the objects to send, see (with Git 2.21+) "[git push is very slow for a huge repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56172942/6309)".

Comment: i don;t know what was there but in my case there was only one remote branch master there and i ran into same issue of slow push but when i pulled master and merged it to local branch it is fixed. even there were no large giant files in between still...

Comment: @ShashankBhatt: you may have run into the bug VonC mentions in his answer. The fetch-and-merge might have triggered a repack. Or, you may have run into the case that occurs with depth 1 shallow clones. We don't have enough information about your setup to say.

Answer (score 4):

Note that Git 2.25 fixes an extreme slowdown in pack-objects when you have more than 1023 packs. See below for numbers.

Other option: Git 2.38 (Q3 2022) proposes the new setting [`git -c push.useBitmaps=false push`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73012939/6309), to disable packing for `git push`.

But for Git 2.25 fix:

That might have a positive influence on your case, where you have a large number of pack files.

See [commit f66e040](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f66e0401abaa884aa91100b4c155c4d042c47e0d) (11 Nov 2019) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8faff38](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8faff3899e1fdefbdd143eaf5ce3b96532205bc7), 01 Dec 2019)</sup>

> ### [`pack-objects`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f66e0401abaa884aa91100b4c155c4d042c47e0d): avoid pointless `oe_map_new_pack()` calls
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> Since [43fa44fa3b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/43fa44fa3b68e6570145126892e1e43380d7bb5a) (pack-objects: move `in_pack` out of struct `object_entry,` 2018-04-14), we use a complicated system to save some per-object memory.
>
> Each `object_entry` structs gets a 10-bit field to store the index of the pack it's in. We map those indices into pointers using `packing_data->in_pack_by_idx,` which we initialize at the start of the program.
> If we have 2^10 or more packs, then we instead create an array of pack pointers, one per object. This is `packing_data->in_pack`.
>
> So far so good. But there's one other tricky case: if a new pack arrives after we've initialized `in_pack_by_idx,` it won't have an index yet. We solve that by calling `oe_map_new_pack()`, which just switches on the fly to the less-optimal `in_pack` mechanism, allocating the array and back-filling it for already-seen objects.
>
> But that logic kicks in even when we've switched to it already (whether because we really did see a new pack, or because we had too many packs in the first place). The result doesn't produce a wrong outcome, but it's very slow. What happens is this:
>
> - imagine you have a repo with 500k objects and 2000 packs that you want to repack.
> - before looking at any objects, we call `prepare_in_pack_by_idx()`.
>   It starts allocating an index for each pack.
>   On the 1024th pack, it sees there are too many, so it bails, leaving `in_pack_by_idx` as `NULL`.
> - while actually adding objects to the packing list, we call `oe_set_in_pack()`, which checks whether the pack already has an index.
>   If it's one of the packs after the first 1023, then it doesn't have one, and we'll call `oe_map_new_pack()`.
>
> But there's no useful work for that function to do.
> We're already using `in_pack`, so it just uselessly walks over the complete list of objects, trying to backfill `in_pack`.
>
> And we end up doing this for almost 1000 packs (each of which may be triggered by more than one object). And each time it triggers, we may iterate over up to 500k objects. So in the absolute worst case, this is quadratic in the number of objects.
>
> The solution is simple: we don't need to bother checking whether the pack has an index if we've already converted to using `in_pack,` since by definition we're not going to use it. So we can just push the "does the pack have a valid index" check down into that half of the conditional, where we know we're going to use it.
>
> The current test in p5303 sadly doesn't notice this problem, since it maxes out at 1000 packs. If we add a new test to it at 2000 packs, it does show the improvement:

> ```
> Test                      HEAD^               HEAD
> ```

```
>     ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

> ```
> 5303.12: repack (2000)    26.72(39.68+0.67)   15.70(28.70+0.66) -41.2%
> ```
>
> However, these many-pack test cases are rather expensive to run, so adding larger and larger numbers isn't appealing. Instead, we can show it off more easily by using `GIT_TEST_FULL_IN_PACK_ARRAY,` which forces us into the absolute worst case: no pack has an index, so we'll trigger `oe_map_new_pack()` pointlessly for every single object, making it truly quadratic.
>
> Here are the numbers (on [git.git](https://github.com/git/git)) with the included change to p5303:
>
> ```
> Test                      HEAD^               HEAD
> ```

```
>     ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

> ```
> 5303.3: rev-list (1)      2.05(1.98+0.06)     2.06(1.99+0.06) +0.5%
> 5303.4: repack (1)        33.45(33.46+0.19)   2.75(2.73+0.22) -91.8%
> 5303.6: rev-list (50)     2.07(2.01+0.06)     2.06(2.01+0.05) -0.5%
> 5303.7: repack (50)       34.21(35.18+0.16)   3.49(4.50+0.12) -89.8%
> 5303.9: rev-list (1000)   2.87(2.78+0.08)     2.88(2.80+0.07) +0.3%
> 5303.10: repack (1000)    41.26(51.30+0.47)   10.75(20.75+0.44) -73.9%
> ```
>
> Again, those improvements aren't realistic for the 1-pack case (because in the real world, the full-array solution doesn't kick in), but it's more useful to be testing the more-complicated code path.
>
> While we're looking at this issue, we'll tweak one more thing: in `oe_map_new_pack()`, we call `REALLOC_ARRAY(pack->in_pack)`. But we'd never expect to get here unless we're back-filling it for the first time, in which case it would be `NULL`.
> So let's switch that to `ALLOC_ARRAY()` for clarity, and add a BUG() to document the expectation. Unfortunately this code isn't well-covered in the test suite because it's inherently racy (it only kicks in if somebody else adds a new pack while we're in the middle of repacking).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just happened to unintenionally add a really large file to my commit.