# Git server working slowly - cloning and pushing

Tags: git, gitlab, push, repo

I have a Repository which is 150 mb size total and there are about 100 commits to it.

In the last day commiting and cloning is really slow - 
It seems that when I clone the repo/push it takes 'cached delta files' and then it can take more than 10 minutes to push or clone.
What can be the cause to such slowness?

Comment: What files do you have that make your repository 150MB? If you have binaries/large test files etc, they should be stored using [git lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com/)

Answer (score 1):

GitLab itself (the remote side of your clone/push) [seems fine](https://status.gitlab.com/).
Beside externalizing large artifacts in [LFS](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/spec.md), you might consider:

- upgrading to the latest Git version (2.25.x, soon 2.26)
- activating `git config --global pack.sparse true`, as I [describe here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56172942/6309).

For large repositories, that can help.